# MediaTek Firmware not working on Debian 11.2.0

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware

I have an Asus VivoBook 5, which has a mediatek wifi card and no ethernet port. The stable/offical debian 11 distro does not seem to have mediatek firmware and I am new to installing firmware on linux.

I have a kali 2021.4a live image which does have the firmware and on which wifi works, I know kali is based on debian, what do I need to do to get the firmware files working in debian?

There is also this link: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/mediatek?id=948cad200e94d82d339207f8ac7b10f932bd627a

These look to be the same files as I can see in my live kali distro.

Thanks

Comment: The firmware should be located under `/lib/firmware`, trawl though the journal to see which file got loaded, then copy it onto a flash drive and move it across.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the `non-free` software [`firmware-misc-nonfree`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-misc-nonfree):

```
sudo add-apt-repository non-free
sudo add-apt-repository contrib
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

Or edit your sources manually following the [Debian sources.list examples](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list).

Comment: One should _NOT_ use Debian `sources.list` with Kali but follow [Kali advice](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/). As stated in that link _"adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali ... will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break."_. That includes Debian repos.

Answer (score -1):

It is not enabled in the kernel. You need to recompile your kernel, there is no dkms installable package. If you are unfamiliar, and want to learn a bunch. Try. If you do not have the time, USB. -Peace

Comment: Rebuilding a Kali kernel is a dicey thing to recommend, as one shouldn't even use non-Kali repos. That's a fastlane to broken Kali and a dependency hell.